# Proof $(A \cup B) \cap C^\complement$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can I proof the above to be equal to:
$$P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C).$$

I know that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) +P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ but do not know how to deal with the intersect $C^\complement$.

Comment: Use $\cup$ (\cup) for *union* and $\cap$ (\cap) for *intersection*, please.

Comment: $Z \cap \text{not-}C$ is the definition of $Z \setminus C$. See [Set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Definition_2).

Comment: but wouldn't that just give me P(A) +P(B) - p(A $\cap$ B) - C

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: $P((A\cup B)\cap C^\complement)=P(A\cup B)-P((A\cup B)\cap C)$

Hint 2: $P((A\cup B)\cap C)=P((A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C))$

Comment: I got to here: P(A)+P(B) - P(A$\cap$B) - P((A $\cap$ B) $\cup$ (B $\cap$ C))

Comment: That is okay if that second-last $B$ is a typo.  Keep going.

Comment: actually it is...do I need to use a law?

Comment: You've stated the expression for the probability of a union in your post. Just use substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$P((A\cup B)\cap (C^c \cup C)) = P(A\cup B)=P([(A\cup B)\cap C^c]\cup[(A\cup B)\cap C])$

$P([(A\cup B)\cap C^c]\cup[(A\cup B)\cap C])=P((A\cup B)\cap C^c)+P((A\cup B)\cap C)$

$[(A\cup B)\cap C^c] \cap [(A\cup B)\cap C]= \varnothing$

$P((A\cup B)\cap C)=P((A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))=P(A\cap C)+P(B \cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)$

$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

$P((A\cup B)\cap C^c)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B \cap C) + P(A\cap B \cap C)$

Comment: thanks a million...makes a lot of sense now